# Adding two numbers with zero padding in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash

```
var1=00001
var2=00001
expr $var1 + $var2
```

Expected result: `00002`

Actual result: `2`

How can I get the expected result in Bash?

Comment: Do you always get 5 digits?

Comment: yes. i want always 5 digits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
printf "%05d\n" $(expr $var1 + $var2)
```